# Define latex command to create new type of heading

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I'm trying to recreate the following functionality using a custom command:

```
\vspace{.15cm}\noindent\textsc{Low Minor Allele Frequency} 
\\ \noindent
```

Basically a little heading which isn't indented and the next line isn't indented. I tried to do this with a command:

```
\newcommand{\smallHead}[1]{\noindent\vspace{.75cm}\noindent\textsc{ #1 } \\ \noindent}
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly. I wonder if anyone can tell me if there's anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

To remove the indentation in the line following the command, end your command by the following macros:

```
\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
```

As Tobi has said, I wouldn’t really use `\\` here but there’s no real harm in it either.

(The macros require `\makeatletter` before using.)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smallHead}[1]{%
  \vspace{.75cm}\noindent\textsc{ #1 }\vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

should work.

Comment: Are page breaks discouraged after `\smallHead`?

Comment: @ChristianLindig They should be.

Comment: changing \textsc{ #1 } to \textsc{ #1 }\nopagebreak discourages page breaks

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn’t use `\\` in your definition. Try this

```
\newcommand{\smallHead}[1]{%
    \par\vspace{.75cm}\noindent\textsc{#1}%
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces%
}
```

and watch out to not have empty lines between heading an following paragraph.

If you’re using a KOMA-documentclass (starts with scr…) you kan also use the `\minisec`-command an change it's font with `\setkomafont{minisec}…`

Full example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% own command
\newcommand{\smallHead}[1]{%
    \par\vspace{.75cm}\noindent\textsc{#1}%
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces%
}
% with KOMA-class
\setkomafont{minisec}{\normalfont\scshape}
\begin{document}
\section*{own command}
Varaint with your own command:
\smallHead{A Test}
This works \dots
% or
\smallHead{A Test}
%
This works \dots
% doesn't work
\smallHead{A Test}

This not \dots

\section*{KOMA}
With KOMA-Script all three will work:

\minisec{Another Test}
This works \dots

\minisec{Another Test}
%
This works \dots

\minisec{Another Test}

This works \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: “and watch out to not have empty lines between heading an following paragraph” – that’s a problem. ;-)

Comment: @Konrad I know, but I couldn’t remeber the soulution. Thanks for your completion. Maybe you could mention that `\makeatletter … \makeatother` is necessary in your answer and isn’t it better to add a `\par` before the upper `\vspace` (ps. Why am I not able to comment your answer?)