# New line without paragraph indentation

Tags: sectioning, indentation, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Define latex command to create new type of heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16097/define-latex-command-to-create-new-type-of-heading)

I have to create a new command that makes a new heading style. Here is a simplified version:

```
\newcommand{\subheading}[1] {\vspace*{1em}\normalfont {#1}}
```

And a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ucs} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} \usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\subheading}[1] {\vspace*{1em}\normalfont {#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\subheading{One of these subheadings}
\lipsum[1]   

\end{document}
```

The problem here is that the subsequent line will be indented, as LaTeX will interpret it as a new paragraph. Obviously, however, the first line of a new section should not be indented. How can I achieve this?

**Update:** The subheading should also be left aligned, and itself not be indented.

Comment: How about a minimal working example, that shows the problem, so I can see it and try to correct?

Comment: Simple but rather ugly: `\newcommand{\subheading}[1] {\vspace*{1em}\normalfont {#1}\par\vspace*{1ex}\noindent}` and then continue the text immediately, e.g. `\subheading{Guarantee}The guarantee is ...`. If that doesn't work then please do as Tom suggested and provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, should have added a MWE in the first place. Here you go! Also, I noticed that the heading is also indented, which should not be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `KOMA` class. `KOMA` provides the command `minisec`. The space above of `minisec` is set to 1.5ex.

To set the font series you can use `addkomafont` or `setkomafont`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ucs} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\minisec{One of these subheadings}
\lipsum[1]   

\end{document}
```

To create our own `minisec` you can use the internal definition as master:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ucs} \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} \usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newkomafont{subheading}{}
\newcommand\subheading[1]{\@afterindentfalse \vskip 1.0ex
  {\parindent \z@
    \ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
      \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak
    \usekomafont{subheading}#1\par\nobreak}\nobreak%
  \@afterheading
}
\makeatother

\addtokomafont{subheading}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\subheading{One of these subheadings}
\lipsum[1]   

\end{document}
```

One advantage you can use the `KOMA` commands `setkomafont`, `addtokomafont` and `usekomafont`

Answer (score 1):

You could define a heading using LaTeX's `\@startsection` command, such as:

```
\newcounter{subheading}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand{\thesubheading}{\thesubparagraph.\arabic{subheading}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\subheading{\@startsection{subheading}{6}{0pt}
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize}}
\newcommand{\l@subheading}{\bprot@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{7em}}
\newcommand{\subheadingmark}[1]{}
\makeatother
```

The output, when added to your minimal example code, is:

[image: subheading example]

You can customize it as desired. Also a table of contents entry is prepared, if needed.